# sending wrong url to web services

Tags: angularjs, node.js, web-services, express

i am learning node.js, angularjs from internet. suddenly i am very interested to devolving MEAN stock.then started learning from internet so made simple app with web servies and it running both client and server side in node.js with two different ports.here one issue is raise when run angular js the GET request calling differently see below

```js
var module = angular.module("1st_module",[]);


var angular_function = ['$scope','$http',function(number,$http){
    number.a = 0;
    number.b = 0;
    number.doit = function(){
    
        $http({ 
            method : 'GET',
   url : 'http//localhost:1000/ans?a=' + number.a + '&b=' + number.b
        }).then(function(res){
            //sucess
            debugger;
            number.ans = res.data;
            
            
        },function(res){
            //failures
            alert('ERROR Ocured');
            
            
        });
       
    };
 
}];
//adding controler to module 
module.controller('frist_controller',angular_function);
```

this adding two numbers "a" and "b" but error raising like 
[image]

Comment: wrong link was used: `http//` instead of `http://`

Comment: thank you so much yes its working now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong link was used: http// instead of http:// – Aleksey Solovey